# samtools view command not found error

Tags: sam, samtools

When I tried to use samtools to split a bam file based on different chromosomes, I used this command:

```
samtools view input.bam -b chr21 | chr21.bam
```

However, I get error messages like this:

```
-bash: chr21.bam: command not found
[W::hts_idx_load3] The index file is older than the data file: input.bam.bai
```

How could I solve this problem? Thanks in advance~~~

The version I am using is:

```
Program: samtools (Tools for alignments in the SAM format)
Version: 1.10 (using htslib 1.10.2)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try re-indexing your bam file:

```
samtools index input.bam
```

Or update the timestamp via `touch index.bam.bai` but I think re-indexing is safer. You might want to save any original index file first, e.g. via `mv input.bam.bai old_input.bam.bai` or similar

Also I think you meant `> chr21.bam` instead of piping via `| chr21.bam` if you want to save the output file

Comment: Cool! I think the problem is because I use | chr21.bam.